# Paypal Cart - Add Legal Disclaimer

Tags: paypal, shopping-cart

I want to add a general legal disclaimer to the bottom of my paypal cart. Is there a way to add text to the bottom of the paypal cart? Kind of like a footer instead of a header.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a way to add this to the bottom of the shopping cart page through the use of a footer.  What some merchants have done in the past is create an image for the legal disclaimer and then they would use it for the business header image on the checkout page.